# PHP Private Message Reply Function

Tags: php

What I have is a reply script, and I need the page to only use the username echo'd in for a variable, like if Meap sends me a PM and I want to reply to it, when I hit the reply link I need it to use his name, and not another name from the page. Currently it is using the first name on the page instead of the one that the reply link is for

Here's the code;

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  session_start();
    $reply = $row['from'];
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  echo '<div class="vpside">';
    if(!empty($row['picture'])) {
    echo '<img class="pictest" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . 'nopic.png' . '" />';
    }
  if(!empty($row['from'])) {
      echo '<p>From:<br />' . $row['from'] . '</p>';
      $_SESSION['reply'] =  $row['from'];
      echo '<a href="reply.php">Reply</a>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['rank'])) {
      echo '<p>Rank:<br />' . $row['rank'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender:<br /> ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
  }  
  echo '</div>';

    if(!empty($row['title'])) {
        echo'<h4><u>' .$row['title']. '</u></h4>';
    }
      if(!empty($row['msg'])) {
      echo '<p class="">' . $row['msg'] . '</p>';
    }
        echo '<div class="sig">';
      if(!empty($row['bio'])) {
      echo '<p>' . $row['bio'] . '</p>';
      }
      echo '</div>';
    echo '</div><br />'; 
    }
```

Here's a picture of what it looks like when you get a Private Message;

[image: PM System]

Evidently you have to be specific down to the last detail on here, the question - or rather the problem - is that it is not using the correct recipient for the reply. Say I click reply under Meaps name, it will use Lilpunish instead. Basically it will use the first one loaded, and I need it to use the correct username. How would I do this.?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Danack Are you kidding me?

Comment: no, I'm not kidding. You still haven't asked a question.

Comment: @Danack Re read the question, on the bottom under the big picture; there is now a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
  $_SESSION['reply'] =  $row['from'];
  echo '<a href="reply.php">Reply</a>';
```

Consider what is happening when this code is run multiple times. The first time, it sets the session variable `reply` to Meap. *The next time, when the second message is printed, it sets it to another value.*

What you actually want is to pass who to reply as a part of the link, e.g.

```
echo '<a href="reply.php?to=' . $row['from'] .'">Reply</a>';
```

And then not retrieve the reply-to from $_SESSION. Session variables are not really supposed to be used like this.

Comment: Okay. I partly understand this now, does that make `to` equal to the variable `$row['from']`, so that I would be able to insert it into the database as `to`?

Comment: Sort of. The variable `$_GET['to']` or `$_REQUEST['to']` (they'll have the same value) will have what is passed to it in the URL. You can see what this is if you view source in your web browser.

You pass this to your database, but I'd like to point out that you should be using something like PDO (which prevents SQL injection attacks) and you should either be using foreign keys in your database (which prevent someone from sending a message to a nonexistant user) or at least verify that the user exists.

Comment: There is user verification. So just to be sure, i would do `to = $_GET['to']`

Comment: Essentially, yes. I highly recommend you read more about this (lookup "PHP $_GET" or something like that) as how data is passed between pages is quite important.

Comment: I still haven't exactly figured this out... can you move this to chat please, if you're willing to help?

Comment: Okey dokey [length filter]

Comment: If you want to look at the important part of the code go here, https://www.ccp2.us/mc/osborn.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49338/discussion-between-user3371397-and-osborn)